# populating more than one nodeset

Tags: xml, xslt

I had below input XML.

```
<Body>
<AddressInfo>
<Address>
<PIN>123</PIN>
<Street>CAN</Street>
</Address>
<Address>
<PIN>456</PIN>
<Street>MAN</Street>
</Address>
</AddressInfo>
</Body>
```

My expected output is

```
<SOAPENV>
<Header/>
 <ResponseBody>
 <AddressDetails>
 <UserPIN>123</UserPIN>
 <UserStreet>CAN</UserStreet>
 </AddressDetails>
 <AddressDetails>
 <UserPIN>456</UserPIN>
 <UserStreet>MAN</UserStreet>
 </AddressDetails>
 </ResponseBody>
 </SOAPENV>
```

My problem is when I gave XPATH and extracted values from XML and trying to populate output. I am always getting only first nodeset. Other nodesets are getting ignored. How can I populate multiple nodesets here in my output soap envelope.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the following stylesheet:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()" />
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="Body">
        <SOAPENV>
            <Header/>
            <ResponseBody>
                <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()" />
            </ResponseBody>
        </SOAPENV>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="Address">
        <AddressDetails>
            <UserPIN><xsl:value-of select="PIN" /></UserPIN>
            <UserStreet><xsl:value-of select="Street" /></UserStreet>
        </AddressDetails>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

If you do not want to write down all elements below `AddressDetails` and all these elements need the text `User` in front of it, you can use a `xsl:for-each` loop like this:

```
<xsl:template match="Address">
    <AddressDetails>
        <xsl:for-each select="*">
            <xsl:element name="User{name()}">
                <xsl:value-of select="." />
            </xsl:element>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </AddressDetails>
</xsl:template>
```

Just replace the other template with this one.

Comment: HI forum, The first case worked for me, I agreed as it gave me instant solution. Now, I want to know how it worked. can any one explain what we did here by using apply templates to @*Node. I can see, the result varying when i changed the fields. any one free to tell me. TIA.